# Angular JS controller function not working

Tags: angularjs

```js
 function studentController($scope) {
            $scope.student = {
                firstName: "Mahesh",
                lastName: "Parashar",
                fullName: function () {
                    var studentObject;
                    studentObject = $scope.student;
                    return studentObject.firstName + " " + studentObject.lastName;
                }
            };
        }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Angular JS Controller</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>
        AngularJS Sample Application</h2>
    <div ng-app="" ng-controller="studentController">
        Enter first name:
        <input type="text" ng-model="student.firstName"><br>
        <br>
        Enter last name:
        <input type="text" ng-model="student.lastName"><br>
        <br>
        You are entering: {{student.fullName()}}
    </div>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js">
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

While loading this into internet explorer I am not getting the full name. It is just showing as {{student.fullName()}}.

Why I am not getting the fullname?
Am I doing any wrong?

Comment: you have to declare a module that will be in `ng-app` or use the `angular.bootstrap` somewhere in your code. Otherwise your app is not considered as an Angular app.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the part where you declare:
- the main angular module. The one that you put in the `ng-app` attribute (if you don't do that, you don't have an Angular app)
- you declare your Angular controller and attach it to the main module.

Replace

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="studentController">
```

by

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="studentController">
```

And in your script, add

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('studentController',['$scope', studentController]);
```

just before your function.

Also, I don't see where you link your script to the HTML document (there should be another `<script>` tag somewhere, after the one for loading the Angular library, for that).

Answer (score 0):

Change object property `fullName` to this:

```
 $scope.student = {
                    firstName: "Mahesh",
                    lastName: "Parashar",
                    fullName: function () {
                        return $scope.student.firstName + " " + $scope.student.lastName;
                    }
                };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to init app module in code, and attach you controller to this module.

```
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.controller('controllerName', controllerFunc)
```

Also, you need to add root module name to ng-app, like

```
ng-app="App"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you will add angular `src` before body tag. It will be better if you will add the line of code inside header section.